# Как создавать новые экземпляры объекта в цикле?

Tags: java, ооп, объекты, циклы

```
static ArrayList<SomeClass> arr;
public static void main(String[] args) {
   arr = new ArrayList<>();
   GenerateNewObjects(new SomeClass, 3); //Вот тут надо создавать новый экземпляр
}

public static void GenerateNewObjects(SomeClass obj, int count) {
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
      arr.add(i, obj);
   }
}
```

Класс `SomeClass` абстрактный

Сделал так:

```
static ArrayList<SomeClass> arr;
public static void main(String[] args) {
   arr = new ArrayList<>();
   GenerateNewObjects(new SomeClass1, 3); //SomeClass1 extends SomeClass
}

public static void GenerateNewObjects(SomeClass obj, int count) {
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
      arr.add(i, obj.getClass().newInstance(), c);
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подойдет?

```
static ArrayList<SomeClass> arr;

public static void main(String[] args) {
   arr = new ArrayList<>();
   GenerateNewObjects(3);
}

public static void GenerateNewObjects(int count) {
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
      arr.add(i, new SomeClass());
   }
}
```

UPD. Если `SomeClass` - абстрактный, а в `arr` можно помещать только наследников, то могу предложить следующий код:

```
    public static ArrayList<SomeClass> arr;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception  {
        arr = new ArrayList<>();
        GenerateNewObjects("test.TestClass", 3);

        for (SomeClass items : arr) {
            System.out.println(items);
        }
    }

    public static void GenerateNewObjects(String objClass, int count) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {   
        // Если передаваемое имя является наследником SomeClass, то пихаем в лист
        if (Class.forName(objClass).newInstance() instanceof  SomeClass) {
        //if (SomeClass.class.isInstance(Class.forName(objClass).newInstance())) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                arr.add(i, (SomeClass) Class.forName(objClass).newInstance());
            }
        }
    }
```

Проверять на `SomeClass` можно даже не в методе, а перед его вызовом:

```
String objClass = "test.TestClass";
if (Class.forName(objClass).newInstance() instanceof  SomeClass) {
    GenerateNewObjects(objClass, 3);    
}
```

А в методе уже не обязательно тогда

---

**Дополнение!**

Как советует @zRrr:

> Чтобы лишний объект не создавать лучше сделать:
>
> `SomeClass.class.isAssignableFrom( Class.forName( objClass ) )` для
>   проверки, является ли класс в строке подтипом `SomeClass`

Comment: Нет. `SomeClass` - это абстрактный класс - от него другие наследуются. Забыл уточнить, извиняюсь

Comment: Можно было сразу написать) Тогда непонятно что вам нужно. Вы хотите помещать в `ArrayList` объекты потомки `someClass` ?

Comment: да, потомки могут быть разными. Точнее они точно будут разными

Comment: @Herrgott сделал апдейт...только проверку на `SomeClass` придется делать в методе, если устроит. Если нет, будем еще думать

Comment: `Class.forName(objClass).newInstance()` во! Именно то, что нужно, спасибо!

Comment: @Herrgott я дописал, что на `SomeClass` можно даже не в методе, а перед его вызовом..... возможно это лучше будет..на всякий случай

Comment: Добавил в вопрос как сделал

Comment: @zRrr Дополнил цитатой от вас. Спасибо за замечание. Я просто искал такой способ, без создания, что-то не нашел, поэтому описал так